# Преобразование CSV в XML по отдельно взятым полям

Tags: python, xml, парсер, csv

Есть `CSV` файл, в котором множество столбцов, из них необходимо выбрать только ряд известных, переименовать и вставить в `xml`.
В примере кода, который есть у меня, происходит выбор по всем полям `CSV` файла. При этом заголовками тегов, становятся заголовки столбцов.

В чем я прошу помощи?
Хочется понять как настроить не диапазон выбора (в примере он от 0 до 10), а конкретный выбор по столбцам, с возможностью переименовать эти столбцы.

```
for i in range(0,10):
    xmlData.write('    ' + '<' + tags[i] + '>' \
    + row[i] + '</' + tags[i] + '>' + "\n");
```

Сам пример кода:

```
import csv

csvFile = 'test.csv'
xmlFile = 'test.xml'

csvData = csv.reader(open(csvFile))
xmlData = open(xmlFile, 'w')
xmlData.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' + "\n")
xmlData.write('<csv_data>' + "\n")

rowNum = 0
for row in csvData:
    if rowNum == 0:
        tags = row
        for i in range(len(tags)):
            tags[i] = tags[i].replace(' ', '_')
    else: 
        for i in range(0,10):
            xmlData.write('<test>' + '<' + tags[i] + '>' \
                          + row[i] + '</' + tags[i] + '>' + "\n");
        xmlData.write('</test>' + "\n")

    rowNum +=1

xmlData.write('</csv_data>' + "\n")
xmlData.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае стоит прикрутить словарь с номером столбца и названием тэга.

Формат такой:

```
neededTags = {0: None, 1: "ЗаменённыйСтолбец", 2: None, 3: "ЕщёОдинЗаменённыйСтолбец"}
```

"None" означает, что используется имя столбца из CSV.

Вот что можно написать на коленке за 5 минут:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv

csvFile = 'test.csv'
xmlFile = 'test.xml'

csvData = csv.reader(open(csvFile))
xmlData = open(xmlFile, 'w')
xmlData.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' + "\n")
xmlData.write('<csv_data>' + "\n")

neededTags = {0: None, 1: "ЗаменённыйСтолбец", 2: None, 3: "ЕщёОдинЗаменённыйСтолбец"}

rowNum = 0
for row in csvData:
    if rowNum == 0:
        tags = row
        for i in range(len(tags)):
            tags[i] = tags[i].replace(' ', '_')
    else:
        xmlData.write('<test>' + "\n")
        for i in neededTags.keys():
            try:
                tag = tags[i]
                if neededTags[i] is not None:
                    tag = neededTags[i]
                xmlData.write('    <' + tag + '>' + row[i] + '</' + tag + '>' + "\n")
            except (KeyError, IndexError):
                pass
        xmlData.write('</test>' + "\n")

    rowNum +=1

xmlData.write('</csv_data>' + "\n")
xmlData.close()
```

Конечно, пурист будет ругаться за написание XML принтом вручную, но это решение выполняет свою задачу.

Comment: Артем - это полностью выполняет свою задачу. Спасибо большое!